# how to show and hide some tab using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

In my code below what i am trying to achieve is when i click on home checkbox then only home tab is open and when i click on menu 1 checkbox then menu 1 tab is show and when i click on menu 2 checkbox  then
menu 2 tab is show.

but in my below code when i click on home checkbox then home tab menu 1 tab and menu 2 tab all are show is not work what i am try to achieve

but i want to make according to checkbox tab is open and close

anyone help me in this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}


function myFunction1() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label for="myCheck">Home:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<label for="myCheck">Menu1:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction1()">

<label for="myCheck">Menu2:</label> 
<input type="checkbox">

<div class="container" id="text" style="display:none">
 
  <br>
  <!-- Nav pills -->
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any body know about this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is what you are asking for...

```js
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const tabs = document.querySelectorAll(".tab");
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]');

function myFunction(event) {
  const menu = document.getElementById(event.dataset.menu);
  
  function hideAll(){
    tabs.forEach((tab) =>{
       tab.style.display = "none";
       tab.classList.remove("active");
     });
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
      checkbox.checked = false;
    });
    event.checked = true;
  }
  
  if (event.checked == true){
    hideAll();
    text.style.display = "block";
    menu.style.display = "block";
    menu.classList.add("active");
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
     hideAll();
  }
}


checkboxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
  checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=>{myFunction(checkbox);});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label for="myCheck">Home:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-menu="home" >

<label for="myCheck1">Menu1:</label> 
<input id="myCheck1" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu1" >

<label for="myCheck2">Menu2:</label> 
<input id="myCheck2" data-menu="menu2" type="checkbox" >

<div class="container" id="text" style="display:none">
 

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active tab"><br/>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You also had the same "for" attribute for all labels and that made them trigger the first checkbox. Now using the code above you can add the ID class of the content-tab as data-menu="idOfThatTab".

Comment: I want to make when click on home check box then home tab is open and when I click menu1 checkbox then menu1 tab is open.

Comment: In ur code when I click the check box then nothing will show

Comment: Can u plz show me something what u doing in above ur code

Comment: Sorry i dont get what you mean when you say "when I click the check box then nothing will show". It toggles between the tabs. From your html i removed the <!-- Nav pills --> part as it seems redundant. Do you have some example online of what you are trying to make.

Comment: Ok I will explain

Comment: I try  to make in above code when I am click on home check box right then home nav pills and home tab panes is show and when I unchecked it's hide okk and when I checked menu 1 check box then menu 1 nav pills and menu1 tab panes is show and when I unchecked then it's hide ..like that show and hide functionality like that

Comment: I created another answer

Answer (score 0):

After your comments I'm still not sure if that's what you need

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]');

function myFunction(event) {
  const menuVal = event.dataset.menu;
  const menu = document.querySelector(`[data-pill=${menuVal}]`);
 
  
  if (event.checked == true){
    menu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
}


checkboxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
  checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=>{myFunction(checkbox);});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label for="myCheck">Home:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-menu="home" >

<label for="myCheck1">Menu1:</label> 
<input id="myCheck1" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu1" >

<label for="myCheck2">Menu2:</label> 
<input id="myCheck2" data-menu="menu2" type="checkbox" >

<div class="container" id="text">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="home" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="menu1" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="menu2" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>


   <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is fine but i also want when i click on home 1 checkbox  tab content is also showing right now in ur code when i click on home checkbox only nav pills is showing

Comment: how can we show also tab content is there any help is it possible???

Comment: yup it is possible I've made an edit for you, try it now.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[data-menu]');

function myFunction(event) {
  const menuVal = event.dataset.menu;
  const menu = document.querySelector(`[data-pill=${menuVal}]`);
 
  
  if (event.checked == true){
    menu.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    menu.style.display = "none";
  }
}


checkboxes.forEach((checkbox)=>{
  checkbox.addEventListener('change',()=>{myFunction(checkbox);});
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<label for="myCheck">Home:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" data-menu="home" >

<label for="myCheck1">Menu1:</label> 
<input id="myCheck1" type="checkbox" data-menu="menu1" >

<label for="myCheck2">Menu2:</label> 
<input id="myCheck2" data-menu="menu2" type="checkbox" >


  <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link " style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="home" href="#home">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="menu1" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" style="display:none" data-toggle="pill" data-pill="menu2" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="container" id="text" style="display:none">
   <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active tab"><br/>
      <h3>HOME1</h3>
       <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 11</h3>
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane tab"><br/>
      <h3>Menu 22</h3>
       <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i above my code i want to show and hide tab content also when i click on checkbox.is there any help ??